# abbreviation with newcommand

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\b}{\begin{frame}}
\newcommand{\e}{\end{frame}}

\b
\titlepage
\e

\section{AAA}
\b
\frametitle{Contents}
\e

\end{document}
```

How to fix this for abbreviation?

Comment: you can't (simply) do that, use `\begin` and `\end` (it is best to use the environment syntax for all environments)

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and don't try this. This will cause many problems, for example with fragile content and many other things.